# Add some logic while using CLR stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to write validation in stored procedure. This stored procedure uses CLR code to create CLR stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SayHelloVoice    
    @messageText NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @procedureName NVARCHAR(MAX)     
AS     
    EXTERNAL NAME say.[CLRProcedures.SayHi].Voice
GO
```

The above code works perfectly. However, I need to add some validation:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE SayHelloVoice    
    @messageText NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @procedureName NVARCHAR(MAX)     
AS
    IF @messageText IS NULL
       RAISERROR('Custom text', 16,16)  
    -- some other logic here

    EXTERNAL NAME say.[CLRProcedures.SayHi].Voice
GO
```

But SSMS shows an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXTERNAL'.

How can I add some logic while using CLR stored procedure?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to handle the error in the CLR function and pass it back to the RDBMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap it:

```
CREATE OR alter PROCEDURE SayHelloVoice_sub   
  @messageText NVARCHAR(MAX)     
, @procedureName nvarchar(MAX)     
AS     
    EXTERNAL NAME say.[CLRProcedures.SayHi].Voice
GO
```

and

```
CREATE OR alter PROCEDURE SayHelloVoice    
  @messageText NVARCHAR(MAX)     
, @procedureName nvarchar(MAX)     
AS

    IF @messageText IS NULL
       RAISERROR('Custom text', 16,16)  
    -- some other logic here

    EXEC SayHelloVoice_sub @messageText,@procedureName;
GO
```

---

**EDIT:**

If it is about handling `NULL` only then `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT` is the way to go.

> [CREATE FUNCTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
>
> **If RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT is specified in a CLR function, it indicates that SQL Server can return NULL when any of the arguments it receives is NULL, without actually invoking the body of the function.** If the method of a CLR function specified in  already has a custom attribute that indicates RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT, but the CREATE FUNCTION statement indicates CALLED ON NULL INPUT, the CREATE FUNCTION statement takes precedence. The OnNULLCall attribute cannot be specified for CLR table-valued functions.